# Convert sysdate into CET and CEST time with the help of UTC package functions in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where sysdate appears like this 19/01/2015 13:22:05

and i want to convert the the sysdate into CET time which will be        `19/01/2015 14:22:05`

and again i want to convert the sysdate into CEST which will be          `19/01/2015 15:22:05`

```
select to_char(sysdate , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') actual ,
to_char(utc.get_local_date(sysdate ,'LOCATION') ,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') cet,
to_char(utc.get_local_date(sysdate ,'LOCATION')+1/24 ,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  cest
FROM dual
```

and here location is using `Europe/Amsterdam` timezone.

Please suggest is there anyway we can achieve CET and CEST timing without hardcoding +1/24 in the sql and by using UTC package functions.

Please correct me if i am wrong ..

Comment: Which dmbs? (Date/time handling is too often vendor specific...)

Comment: `select current_timestamp at time zone 'CET' from dual`

Comment: @jarlh : Looks like oracle.. `...CET and CEST time with the help of UTC package functions in oracle`

Comment: Why do you want a date in winter displayed in "summer time"?  What are your objections against `+1/24` or `+ INTERVAL '1' HOUR`. That is exactly what "summer time" means: `Add one hour to "normal" local time`. Maybe you can simply pick a time zone of `+02:00`, e.g. `EET`

Answer (score 0):

I never heard anything from `utc.get_local_date`, maybe you mixed it with MySQL.

On Oracle you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') actual,
    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS cet,
    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'CET' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS cest
FROM dual;
```

Problem is `CET` does not cover any Daylight-Saving. In order to cover DST automatically you must use the long timezone name, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS cet
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for the suggestion.
But UTC is the standard package used in oracle plsql for UTC conversions.
When i use UTC.Get_local_date function it resolves my problem of CET timings but it is not resolving CEST timings exactly...
So , currently i am trying to find out the possibilities to find out CEST timings with the help of UTC package..

Comment: Package `UTC` seems to be a component of product **Oracle Transportation Management** but certainly not a standard package of "Oracle Database".

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not provide any function like "AT SUMMER TIME" for timestamps.

Either you use fixed time zones like `CET` or `+01:00` or `+02:00` or you use the time zone region, e.g. `Europe/Amsterdam`.

When you use time zone regions the Daylight-Saving settings are handled automatically, i.e. the output depends on the input day.

It is a bit tricky to say "Display 1st of January as it would be in Summer Time"

For example `SELECT TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Amsterdam') FROM dual;` will always return `+01:00`, no matter if you run this query in summer or winter times.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried for explaining it really helped .. :)